# Is there a Set Theory that permits the treatment of elements as sets

Tags: set-theory

I am drawing up the beginning of a framework for a knowledge representation system in my head.

It's very scanty, and I'm not expecting to publish anything on it for at least 10 years.
 
Anyways, I do have some ideas, for how knowledge would be structured. I'm thinking of something similar to an entity relationship model (only structured using a hierarchical model, and a tree of knowledge, but that hasn't been finalised). For the ER model part, I do want entities to be non atomic. Where an entity can actually be a set of distinct entities (with relations defined on them). I make a distinction between what I'm talking about and entity sets, as the latter does not sufficiently capture what I'm thinking about (unless we treated entity sets as entities). Individual entities, need not be atomic, and I'm thinking of something like recursive definitions.

An entity might actually simply be a smaller instance of the entire knowledge tree construct. Entities need not be atomic, and can be defined in terms of other entities—though there would be some atomic definitions—which would be used in strictly specifying the knowledge tree for each entity, and entities in general. So recursive definitions in terms of smaller knowledge trees would be a major component of the knowledge system I'm conceiving. Entities would be defined in terms of other entities. I have not yet accorded any thought to attributes of an entity, and how/if I'll implement them.
 
-------------------------------------------------END RAMBLING------------------------------------------
So I know very little of anything, which is why I described what I'm trying to do, as Set Theory (I'm thinking of combining it with graph theory) may be a completely wrong way of looking at it—and relevant pointers would be appreciated—assuming I'm not completely clueless, and set theory is of (some) relevance to the knowledge representation system I'm trying to think of, then my question is this:

> Is there any Theory of Sets, in which the elements of a set can themselves be sets?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets  ,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification  ?

Comment: Since you mention ER model you might be better off asking a more computer science oriented question related to Knowledge Representation. It seems Set Theory has little to offer to you in your quest.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've only encountered "elementary naive" set theory ("naive" in the sense of not using a fixed axiom system, "elementary" in the sense of only working with basic set operations - note that even [forming the powerset of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) involves sets of sets!). In most formal set theories - in particular, in [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), the standard set theory - **everything** is a set, so the answer to your question is very much "yes."

(It's also the case in other set theories like [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations), but ZFC is by far the standard one. Other set theories - like ZF(C) or NF with [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) -  which allow non-set objects still allow sets of sets. In fact, I'm not aware of any formal set theory which *disallows* sets of sets!

There's a good mathematical reason for this: plenty of mathematical objects involve sets of sets right in their definitions. For example, a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) is a pair $(X, \tau)$ where $X$ is a set and $\tau$ is a set of subsets of $X$ with certain properties. It's only in very limited contexts, in fact, that we **don't** care about sets of sets - e.g. the lattice of subgroups of a group, or the set of automorphisms of an algebraic structure, or anything involving the word "sheaf," or ....

---

Specifically, here's roughly the picture of the universe which ZFC paints: everything is built from the emptyset by "iteratively" taking powersets. Specifically, the set-theoretic universe $V$ is arranged in "layers." There are things called "[ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number);" these are like natural numbers, but they let us "count past infinity" like $$0, 1, 2, 3, ..., \omega, \omega+1, \omega+2,...,\omega\cdot 2, ..., \omega\cdot 3, ...,\omega^2, ..., \omega^\omega, ..., ..., \omega_1, ...$$ (Obviously this isn't formal, and things like "$\omega_1$" I haven't even *attempted* to define, but hopefully this conveys some of the idea.)

Now we iterate powerset "along the ordinals." Specifically, the ZFC axioms tell us that for each ordinal $\alpha$ there is an $\alpha$th "layer" $V_\alpha$.

- $V_0$ is just the emptyset.
- If $\alpha=\beta+1$ (that is, $\alpha$ is a [successor ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Successor_and_limit_ordinals)), then $V_\alpha=\mathcal{P}(V_\beta)$.
- If $\alpha$ is a [limit ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Successor_and_limit_ordinals), then $V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta\in\alpha} V_\beta$.

(Actually, this can all be subsumed into a single clause, but then that's a bit less easy to think about.) And in fact, the ZFC axioms tell us that *every element of the set-theoretic universe is in some $V_\alpha$*.

---

OPINIONATED ASIDE: The way sets are often introduced sets up a false dichotomy: that there are **sets** and **elements**. This does a great disservice by ignoring the actual role and use of sets in mathematics. One of the features of "modern" (= post-18th-century) mathematics, in my opinion, is the explicit use of sets-of-sets-of...-of-sets, both in analyzing existing mathematical objects and *creating new ones*. And the view that *all objects are sets*, though extremely debatable to put it mildly, played a fundamental role in the development of mathematical logic.

Comment: The last paragraph above above the horizontal line: "It's only in very [?]" seems to be an incomplete thought.

Comment: @Dair Whoops - fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms allow sets of sets. Von Neumann model for natural numbers based on ZF set theory relies on the fact that you can have sets whose elements are sets such as:
{{},{{}}} which models the natural number 2

Comment: The ZFC axioms don't just *allow* sets of sets, they *demand* them: *everything* in ZFC is a set, including elements of sets!

Comment: of course. I was just strictly answering the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The power set, $P(X)$ is the set of subsets of the set X, and is an important example.   Cantor proved $|P (X)|>|X|$, that is, the power set of a set always has higher cardinality than the set itself.   This proves there are infinitely many levels of infinity. ..  This unlocked cantor's "infinite paradise ", where he does arithmetic on these levels. ..

Also,  the famous Russell's paradox involves the set of all sets that aren't members of themselves. ..

Interestingly enough,  the set of all sets can be shown not to exist  (since it would contain it's own power set,  and thus have order greater than itself ).